# Building a data structure and building a model to find a shortest distance in that data structure

Tags: r, algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-algorithm

I have a dataset in below given format:

```
ID1 ID2
A   B
B   Y
C   A
D   B
E   D
```

Consider above relation as friends in Social Media site i.e. **A** is friend of **B** and **B** is friend of **Y** and **D** is friend of **B** hence **A** is linked to **Y** and **D**
I want to build a data structure to store the above relations and also have to find the relation if asked up to 6 degrees of separation.

Please suggest on how best to implement the above problem and what algorithm would be best to find the shortest relations.

PS: I am implementing in R Programming, suggestions on direction on how to implement in R would be really helpful

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: A goog data structure appears to be implemented in package `network`. See the vignette at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/network/index.html and some more in the paper https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v024i02 . I have no own experience but expect a suitable function for finding connections somewhere in package sna...?

Comment: Have a look at the [`igraph`](http://igraph.org/r/) package.

Comment: How can I find degrees of connection?

Comment: user20650 is right, igraph is a networking graph model. It will allow you to measure the distance between all members in your social network with great accuracy. That being said, it is not easy to do. If you want a simpler one shot approach, the open source graph visualization package Gephi is very good! You can do your analysis, and import your results.

Comment: @rishi91991 ; did you look at the igraph page? A quick search for `degree` at http://igraph.org/r/doc/ brings up many matches, similarly shortest paths etc etc